# How to get root through TR069 and read access

Tags: ftp, adsl

I have an ADSL modem and router, its OS is linux. It runs ftp service, and I can read files in its file system, but I have no permission to list files and to write files. It has TR069 protocol connections and can upgrade remotely.It has ssh, but not started.
How can I get root access permission?
Thanks.

Comment: The main chip set is Conexant cx94610. I can download any file through FTP, but I can't browse the file system.
Can I flash it through USB?